# Proof of a corollary

Tags: mathematics, formatting

Suppose we have a **Corollary 1.3** evidently implied by **Theorem 1.1** and **Theorem 1.2.**

How should one go about proving **Corollary 1.3**?

Can we say: **Theorem 1.1** and **Theorem 1.2** evidently imply the following corollary:

**Corollary 1.3**

Or should we write:

**Corollary 1.3**

*Proof*. Corollary 1.3 evidently follows from **Theorem 1.1** and **Theorem 1.2**.

Comment: Both ways are fine and very commonly seen, so it's up to your personal preference.  And "opinion poll" questions are usually discouraged on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Just make sure it really is "evident"!  Few things are more frustrating for a reader than spending a lot of time verifying details that the author said were "evident" or "obvious".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either will do, but the second probably is closer to the style of the rest of the paper. The reviewers may have suggestions that you should follow, but don't obsess over it for a submission.

If the proof isn't obvious from your hints they will likely comment on that as well.

Write it as you like.